# TypeError in python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am learning some python and while doing For loop I got TypeError it says append takes exactly one arguments ( 2 given)

```
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.append(num1, num2)

print(pair_1)
```

> TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: .You cannot append two values in a list,so either append it as a tuple/list or perform separate appends for num1 and num2

Answer (score 0):

It says it right there in the stack trace:

`append()` only takes one argument and you're passing it two values

You might want something like this:

```
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.append([num1, num2])

print(pair_1)
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve here, but this is the output:

```
[[2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [2, 10], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], [3, 10], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 10], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [5, 10], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [6, 10], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9], [7, 10], [8, 3], [8, 4], [8, 5], [8, 6], [8, 7], [8, 8], [8, 9], [8, 10], [9, 3], [9, 4], [9, 5], [9, 6], [9, 7], [9, 8], [9, 9], [9, 10]]
```

Alternatively, you can use `pair_1.extend()` however this will just create a giant list containing duplicates, and I dont see how 'pair' relates with this

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the list's append function takes an iterable as the only argument.

You are giving it two arguments `num1` and `num2`.

You might be trying to do something like this.

```py
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.append([num1, num2])

print(pair_1)
```

Or you might be trying to do something like this

```py
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.extend([num1, num2])

print(pair_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

as the error states, you can only append one element to the list while using append.
So, basically, your call, `pair_1.append(num1, num2)` is wrong. You would want to call it twice, like:

`pair_1.append(num1)
pair_1.append(num2)`

the output shall be as an array of integers, like:
`[2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, ...]`

if you want to store it as pairs, i.e. by using 2d list, you can use:
`pair_1.append([num1, num2])` which is a list of lists or you can use `pair_1.append((num1, num2))` which is a list of tuples

Comment: actually on original code,  i forgot to use double parenthesis that is why it says two argument  given.

Comment: by the parenthesis, if you mean to create a tuple, then you're right

Comment: so your code should be like, `pair_1.append((num1, num2))` notice the double parenthesis, the first is that of the function, while the inside one is for creating a tuple

Answer (score 0):

list.**append**(elmnt) - The append() method appends **one** element to the end of the list. Not two, that's why you get the error.

You have many options with your code:

Option 1:

```
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.append(num1)
        pair_1.append(num2)

print(pair_1)
```

Option 2:

```
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.extend([num1,num2])

print(pair_1)
```

Option 3:

```
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.extend((num1,num2))

print(pair_1)
```

Option 1, 2 and 3 will produce the same result:

```
[2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2, 7, 2, 8, 2, 9, 2, 10, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 6, 3, 7, 3, 8, 3, 9, 3, 10, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 7, 4, 8, 4, 9, 4, 10, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 5, 10, 6, 3, 6, 4, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 9, 6, 10, 7, 3, 7, 4, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 7, 10, 8, 3, 8, 4, 8, 5, 8, 6, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 10, 9, 3, 9, 4, 9, 5, 9, 6, 9, 7, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10]
```

Option 4:

```
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.append([num1,num2])
print(pair_1)
```

with output:

```
[[2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [2, 9], [2, 10], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [3, 8], [3, 9], [3, 10], [4, 3], [4, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [4, 9], [4, 10], [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [5, 9], [5, 10], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [6, 6], [6, 7], [6, 8], [6, 9], [6, 10], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5], [7, 6], [7, 7], [7, 8], [7, 9], [7, 10], [8, 3], [8, 4], [8, 5], [8, 6], [8, 7], [8, 8], [8, 9], [8, 10], [9, 3], [9, 4], [9, 5], [9, 6], [9, 7], [9, 8], [9, 9], [9, 10]]
```

and option 5:

```
pair_1 = []
for num1 in range(2,10):
    for num2 in range(3,11):
        pair_1.append((num1,num2))

print(pair_1)
```

will give you:

```
[(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 10), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 10), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9), (5, 10), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9), (6, 10), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (7, 10), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (8, 10), (9, 3), (9, 4), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9), (9, 10)]
```